# C# MVC Entity Framework only saving last row

Tags: c#, entity-framework, csv

I have problem with saving records to my db Table from a CSV file. It only seems to save the last record to the database table in the CSV file? I have modified the code multiple times and can't see where I am going wrong?

I have stepped through the code and can see the records are successfully added to the `List<location> list` and then finally added to the Entity `AddRange`.

Any suggestion?

```
public void SaveFilesDetails(DataTable dt)
{
     Location loc = new Location();
     List<Location> list = new List<Location>();
     foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
     {
         loc.Postcode = row["Postcode"].ToString();
         loc.Latitude = row["Latitude"].ToString();
         loc.Longitude = row["Longitude"].ToString();
         loc.County = row["County"].ToString();
         loc.District = row["District"].ToString();
         loc.Ward = row["Ward"].ToString();
         loc.CountryRegion = row["CountryRegion"].ToString();
         list.Add(loc);
     }

     using (PostCodesEntities dataContext = new PostCodesEntities())
     {                
         dataContext.Locations.AddRange(list);                
         dataContext.SaveChanges();
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create `new object` of `Location`  inside loop. You have declared it outside the loop and it is only getting `value` of `last row` so only one `object` is being stored in the `list` and only one is being saved.

```
public void SaveFilesDetails(DataTable dt)
{

     List<Location> list = new List<Location>();
     foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
     {
         Location loc = new Location();
         loc.Postcode = row["Postcode"].ToString();
         loc.Latitude = row["Latitude"].ToString();
         loc.Longitude = row["Longitude"].ToString();
         loc.County = row["County"].ToString();
         loc.District = row["District"].ToString();
         loc.Ward = row["Ward"].ToString();
         loc.CountryRegion = row["CountryRegion"].ToString();
         list.Add(loc);
     }

     using (PostCodesEntities dataContext = new PostCodesEntities())
     {                
         dataContext.Locations.AddRange(list);                
         dataContext.SaveChanges();
     }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Mairaj for pointing out the problem. It is working fine now :)

Answer (score 3):

Move the `Location loc = new Location();` inside the foreach loop You are overwriting it every time the loop runs.

Comment: Thanks pparas I see where I am wrong now. Works great now :)